# Basic use of useState

Tags: block-editor

Updating the state only renders the button (see attached video) instead entire component. Isn't React supposed to render the entire component the state belongs to?

https://youtube.com/shorts/FjcZE-sWh3c

```
export default function Edit({ className, attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const [video, setVideo] = useState("3TgzifjO15g");

    const addVideo = () => {
        setVideo(attributes.videoId);
    };

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <TextControl
                    label="YouTube video ID"
                    help="Algo parecido a: DyTCOwB0DVw"
                    className={className}
                    value={attributes.videoId}
                    onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ videoId: val })}
                />
                <Button isPrimary onClick={addVideo}>
                    Añadir vídeo. añadido: {video}
                </Button>
                <Player controls>
                    <Youtube videoId={video} />
                </Player>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code, what's the reason you're using state? It would be much simpler if you eliminated the button completely, and used `<Youtube videoId={attributes.videoId} />` instead. At the moment it's possible for the youtube player to show one video, but a different video gets saved because you didn't click the button to preview it. ( `useState` is not the source of your problem )

Comment: also I suspect what you actually wanted to do at first was set the state for the text control when changes happened, not the attribute, then set the attribute in the callback, not the other way around

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am in an early stage of my learning and I am still very confused about the use of React in general and its application in Gutenberg. The reason for using useState is to update the Player component without having to save the post. Using `<Youtube videoId={attributes.videoId} />` only updates the video after saving the post.

Comment: you want to prefer the attributes whenever possible, `setState` is never stored or saved. If you don't modify the attributes then WP will never know the post was modified and the update will not be saved. I would also use the attributes not the state to set your default video ID, and the attribute to set your state, but i do not believe you need to use state at all here

Answer (score 0):

This works. I'm not sure why, but separating the Player component in other component I can update the component from the button callback.

Just to explain the use of useState here: the `videoId` attribute is saved in the comment delimiter block when saving the post. That is something that has already been achieved, it is not a problem. That I needed is a way to preview the video in a player inside the editor when it was chosen in the `TextControl` component.

This player cannot be rendered with the `Texcontrol` `onChange` callback because it will try to update with each character typed. For that reason I have included a button that updates the player when the ID is already fully written.

```
export default function Edit({ className, attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const [video, setVideo] = useState("");

    const addVideo = () => {
        setVideo(attributes.videoId);
    };

    const AgVideo = () => {
        return (
            <Player controls>
                <Youtube videoId={video} />
            </Player>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <div>
                <TextControl
                    label="YouTube video ID"
                    help="Algo parecido a: DyTCOwB0DVw"
                    className={className}
                    value={attributes.videoId}
                    onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ videoId: val })}
                />
                <Button isPrimary onClick={addVideo}>
                    Añadir vídeo. añadido: {video}
                </Button>
                <AgVideo />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```